# how to provide a content type variable to region--header.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I want to hide some inline html from header for specific content type. How cud I provide a content type variable to region--header.tpl.php to put a php condition to hide the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
https://www.drupal.org/node/115419

```
<?php
  // Only show if $match is true
  $match = false;
  // Which node types
  $types = array('book', 'news', 'anothernodetype' );
  // Match current node type with array of types
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
    $type = $node->type;
    $match |= in_array($type, $types);
  }
  return $match;
?>
```